# Query with count is slow

Tags: mysql

I'm having issues with a MySQL count query that takes much longer than I would expect. The query is:

```
SELECT count(1) FROM pages WHERE site_id = 123456 AND online = 1 AND ignored = 0
```

The query runs on a table with about 5 million records, and 2GB in size.

This query takes around 2 seconds, which is much slower than I would expect. My application has many largers tables and more complex queries, and these all run much faster.

When I run an EXPLAIN on the query, I can see it's using an index. I recently ran an OPTIMIZE on the table, but that did not result in any noticeable improvements.

Is there a way to improve the performance of these queries?

*edit*

The CREATE query:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`created` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`modified` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`site_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`path` LONGTEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
`online` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '1',
`ignored` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`redirected_to_page_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`latest_http_response` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
`noindex_nofollow_result` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin',
`deleted` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `Index 2` (`site_id`, `online`, `ignored`, `redirected_to_page_id`, `deleted`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `Index 4` (`site_id`, `deleted`, `noindex_nofollow_result`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `Index 5` (`crawl_job_id`) USING BTREE,
INDEX `Index 3` (`site_id`, `latest_http_response`, `online`, `ignored`, `deleted`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_bin'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
AUTO_INCREMENT=13135003;
```

The result of the EXPLAIN

---

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | pages |  | ref | Index 2,Index 4,Index 3 | Index 2 | 8 | const,const,const | 184 | 100,00 | Using index |

Comment: could you show us the table detals by running SHOW CREATE TABLE pages;

Comment: Please include the plan you saw and the index definitions too

Comment: *"My application has many largers tables and more complex queries, and these all run much faster."* - some application cached their query result in memory though, don't use them as benchmark willy-nilly.

Comment: Added the SHOW CREATE TABLE and the result of the EXPLAIN query

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` disagrees with the `SELECT`.  You seem to be checking `online` and `ignored`.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the query initially. Will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

What was the `COUNT(*)` from the query?  The larger the number, the longer it takes -- given that you have a suitable index.

`EXPLAIN` shows that it is using the best available index.  The main clue is "Using index" which means "covering".  Furthermore, there is essentially no significantly better index.  I also checked the datatypes of the columns and saw no significant issues.

Run the `SELECT` twice.  The second run may run significantly faster -- simply because of caching in the buffer_pool.  (So, when asking about query speed, run the query twice.)

`OPTIMIZE TABLE` is almost always useless (and takes time).  In rare cases `ANALYZE TABLE` (very fast) helps.  I don't recommend either.

> more complex queries

Speeding up one query will not necessarily have any impact on other queries.  You are welcome to present 'complex' queries (plus CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN) in this forum for advice.

Comment: Thanks! The number is relatively low, never over 2500. And yes, running the query again makes it almost instant.